# Get refs via function call

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to replicate the React code from [this official guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html):

```
  render: function() {
    return <TextInput ref={(c) => this._input = c} />;
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this._input.focus();
  },
```

Basically, I'm using ES5 and tried this:

```
 componentDidMount: function() {
        this.searchBox.focus();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <input type="text" ref={function(c) {this.searchBox = c}} />
        );
    }
```

But I got an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
```

Isn't the code above supposed to be the same like the ES6 version? I don't get it why it's not working. In case you're interested in the full code, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/xpd85ehx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES5 and ES6 arrow notations use a different `this`.

Specifically, using the arrow notation, `this` is lexically bound to the surrounding function (so it refers to the class).

Using ES5 you will need to bind `this` to your function.

Answer (score 1):

The es6 version uses arrow functions, which auto-binds the function to the existing scope. so for example,

```
function(c) {this.searchBox = c}
```

is not bound to the instance of the component, while

```
c => this.searchBox = c
```

is. In the first example, its hard to know what `this` is, but in the second, we can be pretty sure that `this` is a reference to our component`. If you want to make your solution work in es5, you need to manually bind, like this

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <input type="text" ref={(function(c) {this.searchBox = c}).bind(this)} />
    );
}
```